# Best approach for saving custom form? (Rails/Backbone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm building a tool that will allow an admin user on my app to create custom, data-gathering forms of any length. These forms will be sent out to the users of the app in order to poll results.

The database structure is pretty basic, as follows:

There are **Forms**, **Fields**, and **Subfields**.

Form is top level. Field `belongs_to` a Form, and Subfield `belongs_to` a Field.

Form `has_many` Fields, and Field `has_many` Subfields.

I want to be able to save from the top down. First, I'll save the Form, and use the ID that's returned to use as the `form_id` for the Fields. Similarly, I want to then save the Fields, one-by-one, and use the returned ID to use as `field_id` in the appropriate Subfield.

These Forms are created with a dynamic form where admin users can add Fields and Subfields by clicking on "Add field" or "Add subfield".

What's the best approach to take for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a gem called ['backbone-nested-attributes'](https://github.com/dtmtec/backbone-nested-attributes) which is working well. It allows you to pass in everything (forms, fields, and subfields) to be saved at the same time as attributes. So my forms controller looks like this:

```
class Api::FormsController < ApiController
  def create
    form = Form.new(form_params)
    if form.save
      render json: form, root: false
    else
      render json: {message: form.errors}, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  private

  def form_params
    params.permit(:name, :parent_id, :completed, :master_copy, fields_attributes: [:name, :field_type, :required, subfields_attributes: [:value, :selected, :name]])
  end
end
```